# jQuery executar uma única ação (método) para vários elementos

Tags: jquery

Tenho um formulário onde uma ação pode ser executada várias vezes por elementos diferentes, gostaria de saber se tem como colocar tudo em uma única chamada. Por exemplo:

```
$("#campo_01").change(function(){
    $("#frmForm").submit();
});

$("#campo_02").change(function(){
    $("#frmForm").submit();
});

$("#campo_03").change(function(){
    $("#frmForm").submit();
});
```

Claro que não é simples assim, pois as funções são mais complexas, com algumas linhas a mais. O exemplo acima é somente para entenderem o que estou querendo.

Será que tem jeito colocar tudo junto, por exemplo:

```
$("#campo_01 #campo_02 #campo_03").change(function(){
    $("#frmForm").submit();
});
```

Comment: Use o seletor de múltiplos elementos, `,`, vírgula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes separa por virgulas dentro da string do seletor assim:

```
$("#campo_01, #campo_02, #campo_03").change(function(){
    $("#frmForm").submit();
})
```

ou ainda assim com o seletor [`^=`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), que quer dizer id "começando por":

```
$('[id^="campo_"]').change(function(){
    $("#frmForm").submit();
})
```

Comment: Interessante isso, seletores semelhantes ao de regex.